# Can Redgard be used to set fiberglass mesh tape on cement board seams?

Tags: shower, tile

I'm using a contractor for a custom tile shower remodel.  He installed Hardiebacker cement board, taped the seams and corners, and then painted on Redgard right over the tape without using any mortar or thinset in the seams.  This does not seem to be the recommended way to use the product, but has anyone had experience with this method?  Will this be OK or should I be concerned?

Answer (score 0):

The TCNA Handbook, which is the Bible for tile installers, doesn't bless his installation. ANSI A108 says to follow the manufacturer's requirements, and James Hardie doesn't like it either:

> • Fill all joints with mortar (see “Materials Required”).
>
> • Embed 2 in wide high-strength alkali-resistant glass fiber tape in the mortar and level.

From the Hardiebacker warranty legalese:

> Product must be installed and used in strict accordance with published James Hardie installation instructions and all applicable laws, regulations and/or building codes.

The contractor's warranty is all you'll have, then.

The tape plus mortar on horizontal joints between studs stiffens up the unsupported edges. If there's blocking behind all of those seams, then I would sleep peacefully. Otherwise, if a tile grout line lands on or near one of the unstiffened horizontal seams, then unlucky pressure from a hand press, for instance, could cause an issue.

As the individual tile dimension measured vertically on the wall increases, the number of horizontal grout lines goes down, and my stress level would go down.

Comment: I have a lot of experience with redgard and like products and have done my share of showers...    I also am very familiar with the TCNA...   And I have always used mortar to secure my cement joints...   My point is with all of my experience I don't find anything inherently wrong with using redgard here.    I am assuming there aren't gaps of more than a 1/16".   I often find mortar is hard to apply without a bulge and the joints under the redgard are a but useless...   This wouldn't be an ANSI standard because they don't have room to give 1000 examples of things you could do.

Answer (score 0):

As has been stated it's all about the strength of the joint.

I have just taped and applied Redguard over butt joints that were tight but were backed with plywood.  Any others had to be mortared and taped.

Almost as important is where the joint is. Will it be subject to any extra pressure and what tile is going over the joint both have to be considered.